# show/hide one DIV at a time, changing link style

Tags: jquery, css, html, styles

It's a while i'm trying to find something what i need and checked lots of links @stackoverflow, @google & etc. but each time some thing isn't working 100%

So problem is about making show/hide DIV's where only one will be opened at once + could be closed on pressing same link, active DIV link should change it's style.

**One of most knows is:** http://dimdajdeneg.com/temp/menu.html
but it's not changing "show DIV" link style & you can't close all DIV's, like if first is open, clicking it again won't close opened one.

**This one is also interesting:** http://dimdajdeneg.com/temp/menu2.html
it even closes it self, but "show DIV" link style isn't changeable

I know that's simple, but probably it's just coz of monday :)
Anyone can help me?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Post some actual code, and show us what you've got so far ?

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com/)

Comment: kindly check two links (http://dimdajdeneg.com/temp/menu.html) & (http://dimdajdeneg.com/temp/menu2.html) sorry, having some temp problem with jsfiddle

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is what i came up with, it fades out everything except the clicked one (inside `.not()`), which gets toggled instead.

**HTML:**

```
<a href="" data-id="d1">Link 1</a>
<a href="" data-id="d2">Link 1</a>
<a href="" data-id="d3">Link 1</a>
<div id="d1">Div 1</div>
<div id="d2">Div 2</div>
<div id="d3">Div 3</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
a {
    background:blue;
    color:red;
}
.active {
    background:green;
    color:white;
}
div{
    display:none;
}
```

**jQuery:**

```
$('a').click(function(ev){
    ev.preventDefault();
    var id = $(this).data('id');
    $('a').not($(this).toggleClass('active')).removeClass('active');

    // parallel fading:      
    $('div').not($('#'+id).fadeToggle(500)).fadeOut(500);
    // OR
    // sequential fading:
    $.when($('div').not($('#'+id)).fadeOut(500)).done(function(){
        $('#'+id).fadeToggle(500)
    });
});
```

**jsFiddle:**

http://jsfiddle.net/fKGc5/

Comment: Thanks it's like 99% what i need, any chance to make it work like, first it disapears and than another DIV fadesout? coz it works like, when you choose another DIV to be shown, you see both fos a second?

Comment: @AleksandrSubots sure, i added a sequential fading block. it's a bit different technique though.

Comment: Works gr8, just last wish, any chance to change A tag to DIV with link inside + adding default class for it, kind of inactive, so clicking it, it would get new class, closing it, it would get back to default?

Comment: @AleksandrSubots you could just give add a class to the A or style A with a default css then change that with active? Or am i missing something? I updated the css. If you want to change the class of a parent div just change the removeClass stuff to: $('a').closest('div').not($(this).closest('div').toggleClass('active')).removeClass('active'); for example.

Comment: Problem is that i can't set class for links properly, i'm adding A links to DIV and they stop showing, with added classes: http://jsfiddle.net/fKGc5/1/

Comment: Sorry, http://jsfiddle.net/fKGc5/3/

Comment: @AleksandrSubots ah that's because of the `$.when($('div')...` in my test. this will fadeOut all divs. change it to: `$.when($('.m_divs>div')...`

Comment: like - http://jsfiddle.net/fKGc5/4/
but again seems to be something wrong?

Comment: @AleksandrSubots yes, but now you have js Error "Object d1 has no method 'data' " because you changed line 3 to `var id = $(this).data('id').data('id');` it should be `var id = $(this).data('id');`

Comment: I would suggest using .hide and .show for better effect :) but thanks for the code, too :)

Answer (score 0):

I have tried the coding in the link : http://dimdajdeneg.com/temp/menu.html

and modified that code as below...

```
function m_slide(m_inactive) {$('.m_box').each(function(index) {
  if ($(this).attr("id") == m_inactive) {
            $(this).toggle("fast");
        }
    else {
            $(this).slideUp(300);
    }
});}
```

In spite of Slide-down`i have used`toggle()`;

Try this fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/RYh7U/92/

Comment: Thanks! But still same problems: you can open more than one DIV + active links isn't changeable ... :(

Comment: @AleksandrSubots : I have updated my code try the fiddle Now... http://jsfiddle.net/RYh7U/92/

Comment: yeap, but still active link "show DIV" stile isn't changeable, when active :(

Comment: @AleksandrSubots : Have you tried this fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/RYh7U/92/ only...?

Comment: yeap, clicking DIV "show DIV" links and it's same style as it is?

Answer (score 0):

If I have understood your question correctly..

Add this to your `.click()` event:

```
$('#linkwrapper > a').each(function () { 

$(this).removeClass("isActive");

});

$(this).addClass("isActive");
```

Obviously you will need CSS for the `isActive` class!